# Partial record from type

Tags: typescript

I've got something like this

```
type Format = 'csv' | 'html' | 'xlsx' | 'pdf';
type Formats = Record<Partial<ReportFormat>, string>;
```

and I would like to create a basic object like

```
{csv: 'A name'}
```

But this runs into the problem `TS2739: Type '{ csv: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReportFormats': html, xlsx, pdf`

Even though I said the object had partial.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this so that the object can be any number of those keys, and so that not all are required?

Thank you

Comment: type Format = {csv: 'ssv' , html: 'html', xlsx: 'xlsx' , pdf: 'pdf'} , partial means partial keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your `Record` a `Partial`:

```
type Format = 'csv' | 'html' | 'xlsx' | 'pdf';
type Formats = Partial<Record<Format, string>>;

const formats: Formats = { csv: 'A name' };
```